# Hackerland Radio Transmitters

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, binary-search

I wanted to do a practice and randomly picked: [Hackerland Radio Transmitters](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/hackerland-radio-transmitters). I highly encourage you to give it a shot, I at least enjoyed working on it.

Please do not proceed if you want to solve it yourself!

To summarize, challenge goes as follows:

> Hackerland is a one-dimensional city with *n* houses, where each house *i* is located at some *x<sub>i</sub>* on the x-axis. The Mayor wants to install radio transmitters on the roofs of the city's houses. Each transmitter has a range, *k*, meaning it can transmit a signal to all houses ≤ *k* units of distance away.
>
> Given a map of Hackerland and the value of *k*, can you find the minimum number of transmitters needed to cover every house?

My implementation is as follows:

```
package biz.tugay;

import java.util.*;

public class HackerlandRadioTransmitters {

    public static int minNumOfTransmitters(int[] houseLocations, int transmitterRange) {
        // Sort and remove duplicates..
        houseLocations = uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations);

        int towerCount = 0;
        for (int nextHouseNotCovered = 0; nextHouseNotCovered < houseLocations.length; ) {
            final int towerLocation = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.findNextTowerIndex(houseLocations, nextHouseNotCovered, transmitterRange);
            towerCount++;
            nextHouseNotCovered = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(houseLocations, towerLocation, transmitterRange);
            if (nextHouseNotCovered == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return towerCount;
    }

    public static int[] uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(final int[] houseLocations) {
        Arrays.sort(houseLocations);
        final HashSet<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        final int[] houseLocationsUnique = new int[houseLocations.length];

        int innerCounter = 0;
        for (int houseLocation : houseLocations) {
            if (integers.contains(houseLocation)) {
                continue;
            }
            houseLocationsUnique[innerCounter] = houseLocation;
            integers.add(houseLocationsUnique[innerCounter]);
            innerCounter++;
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(houseLocationsUnique, innerCounter);
    }

    // Given an array of house locations, INDEX of the starting house that is not covered by a transmitter, and the transmitter range,
    // This method returns the index where the tower can be farthest placed, in order for house at location houseLocations[houseNotCoveredIndex]
    // gets covered.

    // For example an array of {1, 5, 9} indicates the following house locations:
    // .H...H...H
    // 0123456789

    // If house not covered index is 1, this means we need to find the farthest index where we can place the tower on..
    // to cover the house at location = 5 (since houseLocations[1] = 5..
    //      ? -> How to cover this house?
    // .H...H...H
    // 0123456789

    // If transmitter range is 4 for example, index 2 will be fine:
    // .....----T----
    // .H...H...H....
    // 0123456789....

    // If transmitter range is 1, index 1 will be returned:
    // ....-T-.......
    // .H...H...H....
    // 0123456789....
    public static int findNextTowerIndex(final int[] houseLocations, final int houseNotCoveredIndex, final int transmitterRange) {
        final int houseLocationWeWantToCover = houseLocations[houseNotCoveredIndex];
        final int farthestHouseLocationAllowed = houseLocationWeWantToCover + transmitterRange;

        // We need to find the index of the house where house.location is the biggest but <= farthestHouseLocationAllowed!
        int towerIndex = houseNotCoveredIndex;

        while (true) {
            if (towerIndex == houseLocations.length - 1) {
                break;
            }

            if (farthestHouseLocationAllowed >= houseLocations[towerIndex + 1]) {
                towerIndex++;
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        return towerIndex;
    }

    // Given an array of house locations, INDEX of tower and the transmitterRange,
    // This method returns the INDEX of the next house location which is not covered by the tower.
    // Returns -1 if no uncovered houses are found.

    // For example an array of {1, 5, 9} indicates the following house locations:
    // .H...H...H
    // 0123456789

    // If tower index is 1, this means we have a tower on houseLocations[1] (which is 5..):
    // .....T....
    // .H...H...H
    // 0123456789

    // Assume transmitter range is 1, since house at location '9' is NOT covered by (houseLocations[towerIndex] + 1 = 6), this method returns 9
    // Assume transmitter range is 5, since house at location '9' IS covered by (houseLocations[towerIndex] + 5 = 10), this method returns -1
    public static int nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(final int[] houseLocations, final int towerIndex, final int transmitterRange) {
        // This is the farthest tower can cover to..
        final int towerCoversUntil = houseLocations[towerIndex] + transmitterRange;

        // Tower covers the house it sits on already, so the closest candidate is the house at the location pointed by houseLocations[towerIndex + 1].
        int notCoveredHouseIndex = towerIndex + 1;

        // Starting from nextHouseNotCoveredIndex, walk through the array and figure out whether the index we are on
        // is covered by the tower or not.
        // If covered, keep walking, if not covered return the found index.
        while (notCoveredHouseIndex < houseLocations.length) {
            final int locationOfHouseBeingChecked = houseLocations[notCoveredHouseIndex];

            if (locationOfHouseBeingChecked > towerCoversUntil) {
                break; // Tower does not cover the house anymore, break the loop..
            }

            notCoveredHouseIndex++;
        }

        if (notCoveredHouseIndex == houseLocations.length) {
            notCoveredHouseIndex = -1;
        }

        return notCoveredHouseIndex;
    }
}
```

I also have a few test cases:

**FindNextHouseNotCoveredIndexTests**

```
package biz.tugay.test;

import biz.tugay.HackerlandRadioTransmitters;

public class FindNextHouseNotCoveredIndexTests {

    // Run with -ea (enable assertions!)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test_01();
        test_02();
        test_03();
        test_04();
    }

    static void test_01() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int towerIndex = 1;
        final int transmitterRange = 2;
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(houseLocations, towerIndex, transmitterRange);
        assert houseNotCoveredIndex == 2;
    }

    static void test_02() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int towerIndex = 1;
        final int transmitterRange = 5;
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(houseLocations, towerIndex, transmitterRange);
        assert houseNotCoveredIndex == -1;
    }

    static void test_03() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        final int towerIndex = 1;
        final int transmitterRange = 5;
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(houseLocations, towerIndex, transmitterRange);
        assert houseNotCoveredIndex == 7;
    }

    static void test_04() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {5, 10, 100};
        final int towerIndex = 1;
        final int transmitterRange = 15;
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.nextHouseNotCoveredIndex(houseLocations, towerIndex, transmitterRange);
        assert houseNotCoveredIndex == 2;
    }
}
```

**FindTowerIndexTests**

```
package biz.tugay.test;

import biz.tugay.HackerlandRadioTransmitters;

public class FindTowerIndexTests {

    // Run with -ea (enable assertions!)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test_01();
        test_02();
        test_03();
    }

    static void test_01() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = 0;
        final int transmitterRange = 2;

        final int nextTowerIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.findNextTowerIndex(houseLocations, houseNotCoveredIndex, transmitterRange);

        assert nextTowerIndex == 0;
    }

    static void test_02() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = 0;
        final int transmitterRange = 4;

        final int nextTowerIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.findNextTowerIndex(houseLocations, houseNotCoveredIndex, transmitterRange);

        assert nextTowerIndex == 1;
    }

    static void test_03() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int houseNotCoveredIndex = 2;
        final int transmitterRange = 20;

        final int nextTowerIndex = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.findNextTowerIndex(houseLocations, houseNotCoveredIndex, transmitterRange);

        assert nextTowerIndex == 2;
    }
}
```

**MinimumNumberOfTransmittersTest**

```
package biz.tugay.test;

import biz.tugay.HackerlandRadioTransmitters;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinimumNumberOfTransmittersTest {

    // Run with -ea (enable assertions!)
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        test_01();
        test_02();
        test_03();
        test_04();
        test_05();
        test_06();
        test_07();
        test_08();
        test_09();
        test_10();
        test_11();
    }

    static void test_01() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {5, 4, 3};
        final int[] uniqueHouseLocationsSorted = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations);
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[0] == 3;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[1] == 4;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[2] == 5;
    }

    static void test_02() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {5, 4, 4, 3, 1};
        final int[] uniqueHouseLocationsSorted = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations);
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[0] == 1;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[1] == 3;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[2] == 4;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[3] == 5;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted.length == 4;
    }

    static void test_03() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1};
        final int[] uniqueHouseLocationsSorted = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations);
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[0] == 1;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[1] == 2;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted[2] == 3;
        assert uniqueHouseLocationsSorted.length == 3;
    }

    static void test_04() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5};
        final int transmitterRange = 4;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 1;
    }

    static void test_05() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {1, 5, 9};
        final int transmitterRange = 4;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 1;
    }

    static void test_06() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {0, 3, 6, 9};
        final int transmitterRange = 1;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 4;
    }

    static void test_07() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {0};
        final int transmitterRange = 20;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 1;
    }

    static void test_08() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12};
        final int transmitterRange = 2;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 3;
    }

    private static void test_09() throws IOException {
        final File file = new File("test_case_06.txt");
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int[] houseLocations = new int[37455];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 37455; counter++) {
            houseLocations[counter] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        final int[] uniqueHouseLocationsSorted = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations);
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(uniqueHouseLocationsSorted, 80);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 620;
    }

    static void test_10() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12};
        final int transmitterRange = 0;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 8;
    }

    static void test_11() {
        final int[] houseLocations = {};
        final int transmitterRange = 20;
        final int minNumOfTransmitters = HackerlandRadioTransmitters.minNumOfTransmitters(houseLocations, transmitterRange);

        assert minNumOfTransmitters == 0;
    }
}
```

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Both `findNextTowerIndex` and `nextHouseNotCoveredIndex` perform a linear search. Since the array of houses is already sorted, it is better to binary search it. I don't know if something like `lower_bound` of STL is readily available in the Java library, but it is next to trivial to implement.
- Honestly, a line of code spreading to the 140th position is not acceptable. I commend your desire to use descriptive names, but I am afraid you've gone a bit too far. Too much descriptiveness becomes redundancy.
- The decision for `nextHouseNotCoveredIndex` to return `-1` is dubious. It feels much more natural to return just the index, and let the caller test is against `houseLocations.length`.

Comment: I changed the implementation to binary search and gained no performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620487/why-is-arrays-binarysearch-not-improving-the-performance-compared-to-walking-the @vnp

Answer (score 2):

#### Double sort?

The way you sort your input array is like this:

> ```
>     houseLocations = uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(uniqueHouseLocationsSorted(houseLocations));
> ```

Notice how you call your sort function twice.  I'm not sure why you did that but it shouldn't be necessary.

#### Duplicate removal can be simplified

Currently, you sort your input array and then use a `HashSet` to remove duplicates from it.  Actually, removing duplicates from a sorted array can be much simpler than that.

1. Copy the first element of the input array to the output array.
2. For each remaining element, compare the element to the previous element.  If they are equal, then skip it (because it is a duplicate).  Otherwise, copy it to the output array.

This removes the need to create a whole `HashSet` just to check for duplicates.

Comment: ooopps, copy paste error!